# streaming video by origin URL with azure media services

Tags: azure, smooth-streaming

I'm trying to make an app with Smooth Streaming. So I'm doing my app with examples 
[like these](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/media-services/how-to-guides/media-services-dotnet/#header-12%20and%20msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj889436.aspx).

In result I have many URLs. Some of them is URL for files that I encoded, they are like:

```
<mediaservicename>.blob.core.windows.net/asset-d66c43e8-a142-4618-8539-39a2bbb14300/BigBuckBunny_650.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&se=2013-06-23T15%3A21%3A16Z&sr=c&si=aff41a1d-6c8a-4387-8c2f-84272a776ff2&sig=8OPuwW6Kssn2EVQYwqUXkUocc7Qhf0xM62rS9aSPsMk%3D
```

And one of URL is like:

```
<mediaservicename>.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6eca30d3-badd-4f45-bc29-264303ffe84a/BigBuckBunny_3400.ism/Manifest
```

When I try playing the first one on WindowsAzure portal - that's ok.

But when I'm trying to play the second one on WindowsAzure portal  - there is an error "we are unable to connect to the content you've requested. We apologize for the inconvenience".

When I'm trying to play them both in my app with Silverlight they do not play as well as on smf.cloudapp.net / healthmonitor.

Maybe there are some errors in the examples on Windiws Azure site? Or what can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first url you copied cannot be used in a Smooth Streaming player, but the second one may be, if you have created a valid origin locator with a valid access policy.

Can you copy the code you have used to generate these URLs please ?

Hope this helps

Julien

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129575.aspx#create_origin_locator  I use code from this page "GetStreamingOriginLocator"

Comment: i don't change anything in it, but i don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, ok it seems to be good. I think that you are using dynamic packaging to stream you media with Smooth Streaming. In this case, make sure that you have activated a dedicated streaming unit in your media service configuration. See this page : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/media-services/how-to-scale-a-media-service/

Comment: There are several ways to communicate between role instances. You can use Service Bus Messages, Windows Azure Storage Queues or use the internal endpoints of each instance. It depends on what do you want to do exactly... Maybe you can read this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916711/how-to-do-inter-role-communication-with-azure